# close a forked socket client by itself if no any message received in 1 minute

Tags: c, linux, timer, alarm

I write a client/server socket program, when a client connects to server, server fork a child process to handle the communication with the client. when there is no any communication between client and server, Server will kill the client or the client kill itself.

If there are any messages occurred, then the timer will be reset to 60 seconds. and when the time up, the kill task will be submitted to free the resource. Here is the part of server code:

```
signal(SIGALRM, kill_child);

for (;;) {

    if (listen (welcomeSocket,5) == 0)
        printf ("Listening...\n");
    else {
        printf ("Error\n");
        exit (-1);
    }

    // Accept call creates a new socket for the incoming connection
    addr_size = sizeof serverStorage;
    newSocket = accept(welcomeSocket, (struct sockaddr *) &serverStorage,
                     &addr_size);
    switch (pid = fork()) {
    case -1:
        close (newSocket);
        perror ("fork"); /* something went wrong */
        continue;
    case 0: /* child */
        printf("%d CHILD: This is the child process!\n", my_pid);
        printf("%d CHILD: My PID is %d\n", my_pid, my_pid);
        printf("%d CHILD: My parent's PID is %d\n", my_pid, getppid());
        alarm (60);
        /* 
         * Some communication between Server and Client
         */
        break;
    default:
        printf("%d PARENT: This is the parent process!\n", pid);
        printf("%d PARENT: My PID is %d\n", pid, getpid());
        printf("%d PARENT: My child's PID is %d\n", pid, pid);
    } /* end of switch */

} /* end of for */
```

And here it the kill_child func

```
void kill_child(int sig)
{
    if (child_pid != 0)
        kill (child_pid, SIGTERM);
    else
        write ("!!! WARNING !!! kill root process !!! ABORT !!!\n");
}
```

My question is 
1) how to set the timer for this purpose?
and 2) how to reset the timer when any socket message received from client?

`$ uname -a
Linux DMA1 4.4.0-45-generic #66-Ubuntu SMP Wed Oct 19 14:12:37 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: An alternative solution could be to use select() to timeout. Set the socket to be non-blocking, then use select() to wait for data. If select() times out, exit the child.

Comment: Hello @BjornA. Thanks for your hint, I've google some example about use select and timeout tv [How can I implement a timeout on a call to recv()?](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/singlepage/bgnet.html), when I figure out the solution, I'll post it in here.